# Compare tag_totalretailprice with tag_discountprice Business Catalyst

Tags: tags, compare, liquid, business-catalyst

I am wondering what am I doing wrong since it keeps rendering:
"no price"

here is the code:

```
{% if tag_totalretailprice <= tag_discountprice -%}
    <div class="sale">{tag_totalretailprice}</div>
{% else -%}
    <p>no price</p>
{% endif -%}
```

If this helps: I am using `tag_totalretailprice` as the normal market price and I want it to show it(crossed, using CSS class="sale") if the value I put in is higher than the `tag_discountprice`, if not, anything will be displayed.

Can anyone help me with this please?=

Comment: What is the output of `{{tag_totalretailprice | json }}, {{tag_discountprice | json }}` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it and it was passing the wrong output. Although Neido found the way and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the tag_totalretailprice and tag_discountprice to use liquid also like this:

```
{% if this.totalRetailPrice <= this.totalDiscountPrice -%}
        <div class="sale">{tag_totalretailprice}</div>
    {% else -%}
        <p>no price</p>
    {% endif -%}
```

I believe you will get the desired result - at the moment the if statement never returns true which is why your else statement is always displayed.

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you very much!